# Merging when one of the columns is a list, producing a new column that is a list

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have two datasets that I want to merge. One of the columns that I want to use as a key to merge has the values in a list. If any of those values appear in the second dataset’s column, I want the value in the other column to be merged into the first dataset – which might mean there are multiple values, which should be presented as a list.

That is quite hard to explain but hopefully this example data makes it clearer.

**Example data**

```
library(data.table)
mother_dt <- data.table(mother = c("Penny", "Penny", "Anya", "Sam", "Sam", "Sam"), 
                 child = c("Violet", "Prudence", "Erika", "Jake", "Wolf", "Red"))
mother_dt [, children := .(list(unique(child))), by = mother]
mother_dt [, child := NULL]
mother_dt <- unique(mother_dt , by = "mother")

child_dt <- data.table(child = c("Violet", "Prudence", "Erika", "Jake", "Wolf", "Red"), 
                             age = c(10, 8, 9, 6, 5, 2))
```

So for example, the first row in my new dataset would have “Penny” in the`mother` column, a list containing “Violet” and “Prudence” in the `children` column, and a list containing 10 and 8 in the `age` column.

I've tried the following:

```
combined_dt <- mother_dt[, child_age := ifelse(child_dt$child %in% children, 
                                                      .(list(unique(child_dt$age))), NA)
```

But that just contains a list of all the ages in the final row.

I appreciate this is probably quite unusual behaviour but is there a way to achieve it?

Edit: The final datatable would look like this:

```
final_dt <- data.table(mother = c("Penny", "Anya", "Sam"), 
                      children = c(list(c("Violet", "Prudence")), list(c("Erika")), list(c("Jake", "Wolf", "Red"))),
                      age = c(list(c(10, 8)), list(c(9)), list(c(6, 5, 2))))
```

Comment: Could you show the desired output for the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is, first unlist the children, then merge, then list again:

```
mother1 <- mother_dt[,.(children=unlist(children)),by=mother]
mother1[child_dt,on=c(children='child')][,.(children=list(children),age=list(age)),by=mother]
```

Comment: Thanks - I was considering something like this as a workaround but this is more elegant than I was managing to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this-

```
  library(splitstackshape)
  newm <- mother_dt[,.(children=unlist(children)),by=mother]
  final_dt <- merge(newm,child_dt,by.x = "children",by.y = "child")

> aggregate(. ~ mother, data = cv, toString)
      mother         children     age
    1   Anya            Erika       9
    2  Penny Prudence, Violet   8, 10
    3    Sam  Jake, Red, Wolf 6, 2, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the following way, which has the advantage of preserving duplicates in `mother` column when they exist.

```
mother_dt$age <- lapply(
  mother_dt$children, 
  function(x,y) y[x], 
   y = setNames(child_dt$age, child_dt$child))

mother_dt
#    mother        children   age
# 1:  Penny Violet,Prudence 10, 8
# 2:   Anya           Erika     9
# 3:    Sam   Jake,Wolf,Red 6,5,2
```

I translates nicely into *`tidyverse`* syntax :

```
library(tidyverse)
mutate(mother_dt, age = map(children,~.y[.], deframe(child_dt)))
#   mother         children     age
# 1  Penny Violet, Prudence   10, 8
# 2   Anya            Erika       9
# 3    Sam  Jake, Wolf, Red 6, 5, 2
```